How to install 'quota' on SteamOS (KDE) for the Disk Quota Tool?
In Desktop Mode on SteamOS, if you open up the "Status and Notifications" section from the system tray, then there's an option that says "Disk Quota":

But when you click on it, then it says:

Quota tool not found. Please install 'quota'


The issue is that it doesn't tell you how to install 'quota'. There's no instructions or install button. Searching for "quota" in the Discover Store doesn't give any valuable things either:


So how do you actually install the Quota Tool?

The tool you search for is named quota-tools
And the procedure of install is as usual:
pacman -S quota-tools

If you get error with unknown trust you can:
set
SigLevel = TrustAll

under
[options]

in the file
/etc/pacman.conf

Install and then rollback

I get an error when I try to run that. The error I get is the following error: quota-tools: signature from "GitLab CI Package Builder <ci-package-builder-1@steamos.cloud>" is unknown trust :: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/quota-tools-1:4.09-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).

@ShaunRoselt, please check my edited answer

What do you mean by "and then rollback"? Meaning set SigLevel back to what it was before?

@ShaunRoselt, correct
